# PayPal Fetch Token

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I am using the PayPal API for Express Checkout Integration. Upon setting the Express Checkout, one gets to a page with a token, like this page:

```
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
```

The token looks more or less like that

```
ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

My Question is: how do I fetch this toke by means of PHP? I do not want to be redirected to that page beforehand. How do I just fetch the contents of a remote file after passing certain post parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a direct answer, but for PayPal I found the developer forums really good for getting quick answers, especially when its specific to technology (.NET, PHP, etc.)

https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1613

http://paypaldev.org/